# python is there any way to update a list base on a list of pair of (index, values)

Tags: python, numpy, vector

### I am new to python, and I am having trouble with efficiently update a current vector

eg.

```
>>>idx_val_list = [[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5]]
```

or

```
>>>idx_list = [0, 2, 4] 
>>>val_list = [1, 3, 5]
>>>vector = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

looking for an efficient way to achieve batch update something like

```
>>>vector.update(indexes=idx_list, values=val_list) 
>>>vector
[1,0,3,0,5,0,0,0]
```

Is there any efficient way other than for loops to achieve this requirement?

Comment: Look up list comprehensions.

Comment: How big will the initial vector be?  Can indices repeat?  If so, how do you want to handle that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest using [np.put](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.put.html) instead of loops or list comprehension.

Try this;

```
>>> vector = np.array([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])
>>> idx_list = [0, 2, 4]
>>> val_list = [1, 3, 5]
>>> vector
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
>>> np.put(vector, idx_list, val_list)
>>> vector
array([1, 0, 3, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0])
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for idx,val in zip(idx_list, val_list):
  vector[idx] = val
```

Answer (score 2):

```
In [149]: idx_list = [0, 2, 4]
     ...:
     ...: val_list = [1, 3, 5]
     ...:
     ...: vector = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
     ...:

In [150]: for i,j in zip(idx_list, val_list):
     ...:     vector[i] = j
     ...:

In [151]: vector
Out[151]: [1, 0, 3, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have repeating indices, @Memduh has it right using `np.put`

You can also just do `v[idx_list] = val_list`

If you want to accumulate the values in place, you can also use `np.add.at`

```
v = np.array(vector)

np.add.at(v, idx_list, val_list)

v
Out[]: array([1, 0, 3, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0])
```

If your initial vector is going to be very large, you may want to make it a `scipy.sparse.lil_matrix` as this allows directly assigning the values to their locations without assigning zeroes elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Using `numpy`

```
import numpy
vector=numpy.array(vector)
vector[idx_list]=val_list
print vector
```